# Crear una función que al introducir una matriz devuelva otra con el doble de columnas, las columnas nuevas han de ser identicas a las originales

Tags: r, dataframe, matrices, rstudio

Soy nuevo programando en R y estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que me piden crear una función, asumiendo que todas las columnas tienen valores numéricos y que cuentan con una fila llamada 'Medias' que contiene la media de cada una de las columnas, al introducir una matriz a esta función, me tiene que devolver la misma matriz pero con el doble de columnas, es decir, copiar las n columnas que tenga la matriz dada y añadirlo a la derecha de la matriz.

Además el valor de estas nuevas "copias" de las columnas tienen que tener el valor original menos la media de cada columna (que están recogidas en la fila 'Medias').

El dataframe con el que estoy haciendo las pruebas lo pueden obtener aquí:

```
state.df = as.data.frame(state.x77)
state.df = rbind(state.df,Medias=colMeans(state.df,na.rm = T))
```

Estoy un poco perdido en esto ya que he intentado hacer esto:

```
state.df2 = state.df #Para copiar el df
state.df3 = cbind(state.df,state.df2) #Unirlo y crear el df definitivo con el doble de columnas
```

Pero no se como restar en las columnas que van de la 9:16, el valor de la media de esa columna, y además meter esto en una función, ya que con las variables de arriba creo que solo funcionaría para state.df, pero no sirve para meterlo en una función.

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar estaría enormemente agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
mi_funcion <- function(df) {
  row_medias <- tail(df, 1)
  row_resto <- head(df, -1)
  tmp <- rbind(row_resto - as.list(row_medias), row_medias)
  cbind(df, tmp)
}
```

Simplemente dividimos los datos de las medias y los restamos: `row_resto - as.list(row_medias)`, agregamos una fila con la medias simplemente para que sean consistentes los `data.frame` y los combinamos con un `cbind()`

Answer (score 1):

Con el cbind como dices, puedes agregar las columnas, ahora solo te falta eliminar la fila Medias de la ultima base:

Con:

```
 state.df3[nrow(state.df3),(length(state.df2)+1):length(state.df3)]
```

con nrow obtienes las filas y con length el numero de columnas

Usando esto, puedes asignar de manera matricial con NA, es decir, de tu base df3[51,9:16] se convierten en NA. Llevando esto a una función, para que sirva con cualquier df puedes hacer:

```
tu_funcion = function(df) {
  
  state.df = as.data.frame(df)
  state.df = rbind(state.df,Medias=colMeans(state.df,na.rm = T))
  
  state.df2 = state.df #Para copiar el df
  state.df3 = cbind(state.df,state.df2) #Unirlo
  
  state.df3[nrow(state.df3),(length(state.df2)+1):length(state.df3)] = NA
  
  return(state.df3)
  
}

tu_funcion(state.df)
```